# Clicking on the button column of datagrid view an automatic mail will be sent to mail id

Tags: c#, winforms, email, datagridview

I have a datagrid view with three columns and one button column. My aim is that I want to send an automatic email to the specified mail id when I click on the button in button column of the datagrid view.

Is it possible to do so that if I click on the button column, a mail will be sent to this mail id: `abc@shx.com`?

The corresponding row values will be attached to body of the mail. Is it possible to do these three steps:

1. Handling the click event (button column click event)..
2. Finding the corresponding row values and attached to mail body
3. Sending the email to given mail id (if I click on the button column (only on the button))

Would anyone suggest me any ideas for doing these all? I am doing WinForms application using C#.

**EDIT :**

```
private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e) 
{ 
    if (e.ColumnIndex != 3) 
        return; 
    object col1 = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value; 
    object col2 = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value; 
    object col3 = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value; 
}
```

But I don't know how to get the row values and send an email.

Comment: Why shouldn't that be possible? Is your problem to handle the click, or to send the email, or to assess the cell's values?

Comment: @TheBlastOne to send the email and to handle the click and to attach the cell values to mail body..

Comment: Please add this to the question. Or create three separate questions. Others might not answer since all the question asks is "Is it possible?".

Comment: @TheBlastOne I have edited my question would you  pls take a look at my  question

Comment: @TheBlastOne pls see my edit option i have found that for click event and getting the column values ....

Comment: would any one pls help on this one.....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example you already got the row values corresponding to the row being clicked:

```
object col1 = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value; 
object col2 = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value; 
object col3 = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value;
```

as far as sending an email in .NET is concerned, you could use the [SmtpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.aspx) class. Here's an example with Gmail:

```
var client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
client.EnableSsl = true;
client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("youraccount@gmail.com", "secret");

var mail = new MailMessage();
mail.From = new MailAddress("youraccount@yahoo.com");
mail.To.Add("destaccount@gmail.com");
mail.Subject = "This is the subject of the mail";
mail.Body = "This is the body of the mail";
client.Send(mail);
```

Of course you should adapt your Smtp server configuration to match your settings.

Comment: @user844360, simple string formatting: `mail.Body = string.Format("Here are your rows: {0} {1} {2}", col1, col2, col3);`. I don't know how do you want to format your mail.

Comment: I will do the formating but i am not getting the row values... it just crashes the system. is that way is correct to get the row values....

Comment: @user844360, that's the correct to read values from a data grid. What's the problem with it?

Comment: when i click on the button column the system just crashes....with out seeing any error for that i am asking you any alternative to this..

Comment: @user844360, what button are you talking about? Can't see any code in your question related to a button. Or are you talking about clicking on a grid cell? Is this what you call a button? Also wrapping your code in a try/catch would give you more details about the exception you are getting.

Comment: yaa i fixed the  datagrid view last column as a button column button is not occupied in entire cell ,  it  is located in center of cell for that i have modified padding properties for that button cell.. so when i click on the button in that cell it just crashes.....

Comment: @user844360, what does *crashes* mean? You get an exception? Your application closes? Apples start falling from the sky?

Comment: Isn't the `dataGridView1_CellClick` method called?

Comment: You can find out easily by putting a breakpoint on first statement in the handler and hitting f9 for toggle breakpoint, then f5 for run.

Comment: How are you adding the button column to your grid?

Comment: @Darin I found the problem I have already written another function in datagridview1_cellclick i have written this function also in same clcik event...It is causing the problems....

Comment: @user844360, great, I am glad that you finally sorted this out.

Comment: @user844360, no idea. How do you expect me answering this question without knowing what does this function do? All you said about it is I quote: `... function also in same clcik event...It is causing the problems`. Unfortunately this description of your function doesn't allow me to know much about it. How is it implemented and look like.

Comment: I think you are using DataGridViewButtonColumn. And I wonder why there is no "Handles dataGridView1.CellClick" in your dataGridView1_CellClick declaration.